# How do I run mocha test on array of data asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

How do I run same mocha tests to an array of data asynchronously(in parallel)?

This is the code I currently have:

```
const testData = [{'array': 'of data here'}];
describe('run these test to data', () => {
  testData.forEach((data) => {
    describe('mocha test', () => {
      it('asserts data', () => doStuff())
    })
  })
})
```

I tried using [async package each](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each) but the time the tests runs is the same as before.

The goal is to lessen the amount of time the test runs.

Comment: Node.js runs in a single thread, so this can not be done at the level you are expecting to be possible. Try mocha v8+ (and flag --parallel) it supports running tests in parallel, with the same goal, to reduce the time needed to run all tests. Although I'm still not sure about array testing.

Comment: Thanks @BorisKukec. I already have this but the parallel is on different files. One solution I had was to break up the array and put it in different files so if I have 8 items in the array, 4 of the items will be run on a different file.

Comment: Yes, I know about the different files. My thoughts exactly about breaking long array into smaller parts. This seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use it, your problem can be solved.

expect details: https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/

```js
describe('...',() =>{
        it('data tesing',(done) =>{
            expect(data).to.be.an('array')
        } )
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm looking for a solution to run the array of data to be tested at the same time to lessen the time the test runs.